# How to convert a Base64 string to Bitmap on Android?

Tags: android, json, base64, decode

I'm having this problem for converting several Base64 string to  Bitmap images, in my android application.
Now I've looked for solutions for quite a while, but nothing seems to solve my problem.
My application gets JSON data from a server, containing several images in base64. the json code received from the server can be found here : http://pastebin.com/tgiMgqRg
I tried to decode the first image on this website : http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/, and it seems to be correct.

the code to receive the JSON date is :

```
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = sslClient(new DefaultHttpClient());

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            //DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            //DEBUG
            Log.d("JSONParser", "sent request : " + url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

I then try to decode these images using this code :

```
    try {
       images = json.getJSONArray(MapActivity.TAG_LIST);

            // looping through all Images
            for (int i = 0; i < images.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject house = images.getJSONObject(i);
                String photo = house.getString(TAG_PHOTO);
                //Log.d("PHOTO", photo);
                Log.d("PHOTO NUMBER", i + "");

                try {
                    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.URL_SAFE);
                    Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
                    HashMap<String, Bitmap> map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();
                    map.put(TAG_PHOTO, decodedByte);

                    imagesList.add(map);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But i get these errors :

```
    D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 0
D/skia(26854): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 1
D/skia(26854): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 2
D/skia(26854): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 3
W/System.err(26854): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
W/System.err(26854):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
W/System.err(26854):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
W/System.err(26854):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
02W/System.err(26854):  at ...$LoadImages.doInBackground(DisplayHouseInfo.java:225)
W/System.err(26854):    at ...$LoadImages.doInBackground(DisplayHouseInfo.java:1)
W/System.err(26854):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err(26854):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err(26854):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err(26854):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err(26854):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err(26854):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 4
W/System.err(26854): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
W/System.err(26854):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
                                            ...
D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 5
W/System.err(26854): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
W/System.err(26854):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
                                            ...
D/PHOTO NUMBER(26854): 6
W/System.err(26854): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
W/System.err(26854):    at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
                                            ...
02-27 14:57:11.316: E/BitmapFactory(26854): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
I/System.out(26854): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: 
E/BitmapFactory(26854): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
I/System.out(26854): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
```

My problems are : 
- I can't seem to make BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray work
- I get another exception for the lasts images

Do you have any ideas/suggestions on how to solve this ?

Comment: `I can't seem to make BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray work`. No. Your problem lies just before that.  You have an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64`. So on code line 'byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.URL_SAFE);' i suppose.

Comment: Well for the first three iterations of the "for" loop I have a `--- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null` error, which is apparently cast by BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray. I have also a `bad base-64` error on each following iteration of the for loop, which is my second problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three base64 strings which represent images decode ok. But the following four produce a catch with `bad base-64` on line

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

I said that before. If you would use

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

then there are no catches. All 7 base64 strings decode ok.